# Empty Object Repository List in RAD Studio 10.3

Tags: delphi, ide, rad-studio

I've installed new version of RAD Studio 10.3 a couple days ago on my system Windows 10 Pro 64bit. It required to login with admin rights, i did it.
Then I started RAD Studio from non-administrative account, and when IDE started, I clicked "File - New", and all default items from object repository were lost.
There was no items like "Console application", or "Windows Application". Only folder "Other - Unit Test", with three items: "Code Template", "Project Group", "Text File".

Then I restarted RAD Studio from an administrative account. All items were in list: Console Application, Windows Application, FireMonkey Application.
Then I restarted again from non-administrative account. And no items again.

I searched in web for that problem, it seems it doesn't load items from object repository, when logged in from non-administrative account. But what is the reason? I gave full read/write access in every folder of "Environment Variables" for all user.

[image: empty_object_repository]

Comment: The problem was not in the fact that RAD studio failed to load objects from Object repository but instead the fact that it didn't load your licence properly. You RAD studio checks your licence and then only valid objects based on your licence. So by using Licence manager you might have solved this without messing in registry.

Answer (score 2):

The problem solved.
I've executed **regedit.exe**, and deleted branch **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\20.0**

I could rename it, but I had no important settings saved, so I deleted it.

And then I've restarted RAD Studio **from non-administrative account**. Regedit branch was recreated, and everything became fine. Standart project items appeared.
I think that issue was because of first launch of RAD Studio was by admin account. And it created some wrong paths (which exactly, I didn't find).

Now everything is okay.